# Exporting DB as CSV from latin1 encoded strings in to utf-8

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, encoding, utf-8

We have MSSQL 2005 DB with strings encoded as latin1. The requirement is to export it as utf-8 for new DB. I have written following script to export the DB:

```
var sql = require('mssql'); 
var csv = require("fast-csv");
var fs = require("fs");
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');

function exportCSV(tableName) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var csvStream = csv.format({headers: false, quoteColumns: true}),
    writableStream = fs.createWriteStream("Output/"+tableName+".csv",{encoding: "utf8"});

    writableStream.on("finish", function() {
      console.log(tableName+" CSV file exported!");
      resolve();
    });

    csvStream.pipe(writableStream);


    var request = new sql.Request();
    var dateFormat="";
    request.query('select * from '+tableName);

    request.on('row', function(row) {
        // do some processing on row if required
        csvStream.write(row);
    });

    request.on('error', function(err) {
        reject(err);
    });

    request.on('done', function(returnValue) {
        csvStream.end();
    });
  }); 
}
```

Since, I am doing no conversion of encoding some hiphens get converted to

```
â€
```

Now, instead of

```
csvStream.pipe(writableStream);
```

if I write

```
csvStream.pipe(iconv.decodeStream('latin1'))
                .pipe(iconv.encodeStream('utf-8'))
                .pipe(writableStream);
```

Some hiphen get converted to

```
Ã¢Â€Â
```

Comment: The `iconv.encodeStream()` is superfluous as `decodeStream()` already decodes to utf-8. If that doesn't fix your problem, try using `iconv.decodeStream()` as the first stream in your pipe. And also, take a look at [`pipe()`](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#pipestream) provided by `mssql`. In other words: `request.pipe(iconv.decodeStream(...)).pipe(csvStream).pipe(writeableStream)`

Comment: @robertklep i need to pass decoded stream to csvstream, but it gives error: TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk

Comment: Try your original order: `request.pipe(csvStream).pipe(iconv.decodeStream(...)).pipe(writeableStream)`.

Comment: @robertklep i figured out that csvStream corrupts the data ( long hiphen gets converted to â€, i tried your method it worked but  special character â€ was still present. Decoding should occur before stream is passed to csvstream

Comment: AFAIK, Latin-1 doesn't have an encoding for a long hyphen (_"emdash"_ probably), which would mean that your input is "corrupt".

Comment: @robertklep In the schema encoding is mentioned as latin1 and if i export using SQL Server management studio the resultant sql files are ucs2 little endian encoded in which dashes appear properly - no special characters, I tried using ucs2 in node also but it corrupts the data with chinese letters. If I console.log the row before passing it to csvstream it appears correctly, but when written to file corrupts

Comment: Latin-1 also doesn't encode Chinese characters, so my guess is that even though the schema encoding says Latin-1, it actually isn't.

Comment: @robertklep there are no chinese characters, but after exporting they appear if ucs2 is used in node

Answer (score 0):

This is a working program using [node-csv](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv).

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var fs  = require('fs');
var csv = require('csv');

var stream      = fs.createWriteStream('out.csv', {encoding: 'utf8'});
var stringifier = csv.stringify({delimiter: ',', header: false, quoted: true});

var config = {user: '...', password: '...', server  : '...', database: '...',
    stream: true
};

var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {
  var request = new sql.Request(connection);
  request.pipe(stringifier).pipe(stream);
  request.query('SELECT * FROM table');

  stream.on('error',  end);
  stream.on('finish', end);
});

var end = function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error with file stream', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Done with file stream');
  }
  stringifier.end();
  connection.close();
};
```